# How to fix remote ejb lookup in Websphere Liberty?

Tags: ejb, ejb-3.0, websphere-liberty, ejb-3.1

I am trying to access the ejb deployed on websphere liberty 18.0.0.3

The binding location is: java:global/ITSORemote/ITSORemoteEJB/HelloRemoteEJB!com.ibm.itso.ejbRemote.view.HelloRemoteEJBRemote

My ORB configuration in the server.xml is:

```
 <orb nameService="corbaname::<ipaddress>:2809" iiopEndpointRef="defaultIiopEndpoint">

   <iiopEndpoint host= id="defaultIiopEndpoint" iiopPort="2809">
   </iiopEndpoint>

    </orb>
```

I have also added ejbRemote-3.2 in feature manager

**I have two scenarios:**
**1. Access ejb from a client code running on the same server - This works using the url** java:global/ITSORemote/ITSORemoteEJB/HelloRemoteEJB!com.ibm.itso.ejbRemote.view.HelloRemoteEJBRemote
**2. Access ejb from a client code running on the different server - This does not work using the url** 
corbaname::(ipaddress):2809#ejb/global/ITSORemote/ITSORemoteEJB/HelloRemoteEJB!com.ibm.itso.ejbRemote.view.HelloRemoteEJBRemote

I am using the following code for lookup:

```
package com.ibm.remoteaccess;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.ibm.itso.ejbRemote.view.HelloRemoteEJBRemote;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class RemoteAccess
 */
@WebServlet("/RemoteAccess")
public class RemoteAccess extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            out.println("Hi");
            Context ctx = new InitialContext();
            Object ejbBusIntf = ctx.lookup("java:global/ITSORemote/ITSORemoteEJB/HelloRemoteEJB!com.ibm.itso.ejbRemote.view.HelloRemoteEJBRemote");
            HelloRemoteEJBRemote bean = (HelloRemoteEJBRemote)PortableRemoteObject.narrow(ejbBusIntf, HelloRemoteEJBRemote.class);
            out.println(bean.hello());
         }
         catch (NamingException e) { // Error getting the business interface
             out.println(e);
         }
    }

}
```

**There is no error thrown in the console also. What could be the problem?**

Comment: But you write that in case 2, you go with corbaname, shouldnt you not use narrowing ??

Comment: @MrSimpleMind I tried both with narrowing and without narrowing. Both didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a functional acceptance test (FAT) in open-liberty that looks up a remote EJB from one liberty server to an EJB on a second liberty server. The specific test can be found here:

https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/blob/master/dev/com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.remote_fat/test-applications/RemoteClientWeb.war/src/com/ibm/ws/ejbcontainer/remote/client/web/RemoteTxAttrServlet.java

Each server process includes the `ejbRemote-3.2` feature and an iiopEndpoint configuration (different ports since the test runs both serves on the same host).

https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/blob/master/dev/com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.remote_fat/publish/servers/com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.remote.fat.RemoteServerClient/server.xml

If you are not seeing any errors, then perhaps the iiopEndpoint is not configured properly in the client side server (as the ORB will not start without it). For example, the default iiop port is 2809, and if both servers are on the same host, then they cannot both use that port. Setting both servers to the same port would result in the ORB not starting properly on one of the servers, and lookups would fail.

A lookup across servers would use `corbaname`, and the value you have specified appears to be correct.